# SEO question with nuxt-link in a nuxt template

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js

I have a card where for a demand on SEO i need to put the nuxt link on the title but the whole card must be clickable with a method :

```
<template>
  <div @click.prevent="clickit(item)" >
    <img class="background" :src="item.backgroundImage" />
    <nuxt-link
      :to="'/road/' + item.id"
    >{{ item.text }}</nuxt-link>
    <img class="mask" :src="item.backgroundMask" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickit(item) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: "/road/" + item.id
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

So i did like that but the problem is when i click only in the title it fire two events. Is there a way to prevent default in a nuxt link ?

Comment: why do you use nuxt-link ?

Comment: just use `nuxt-link`  as the wrapper of all

Comment: no because in the client side the nuxt-link become a.href link and its better for seo to get only meaning words in it.

Answer (score 0):

i've found the solution :

```
 <nuxt-link
    :to="'/road/' + item.id"
     @click.native="fuga"
     event
     class="ititle"
 >{{road.name}}</nuxt-link>
```

and then i adde this method :

```
fuga(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip: You can also do `@click.native.prevent="fuga"`. Then `e.preventDefault();` is no longer required ;)